# How does one Set the "Pick" Expression for Apache Camel's FlexibleAggregationStrategy in Spring XML?

Tags: xml, spring, apache, apache-camel

I am attempting to configure an Apache Camel route in Spring XML using Apache Camel 2.14. The route will involve either an `<aggregator>` or an `<enrich>`/`<pollEnrich>`; I'm not yet experienced enough with Camel to know which EIP will be most useful. Either way, I'm going to need an `aggregationStrategy`. My end goal involves creating a Camel route for a client who wants the routes configured in XML.

By searching around the Internet, I learned of the existence of a Camel class called `FlexibleAggregationStrategy`. The things I found claim, and I quote, "It allows you to quickly 
whip up an AggregationStrategy that is capable of performing the most typical aggregation duties, with zero Java code." This sounds useful to me, since we want as much of the configuration in XML as possible. As such, it would be nice to avoid writing my own `AggregationStrategy` in Java. The problem is, I can't figure out how to use a `FlexibleAggregationStrategy`.

From what I can tell, the `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` picks elements from messages to aggregate using an `Expression` called `pickExpression`, and filters out messages that match the `Predicate` `conditionPredicate`. So, I assume I need to have a way to set these values in my Spring XML. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get the following blocks of code work:

Property name set to `pickExpression`, value as element:

```
<bean id="FlexibleAggregationStrategy"
    class="org.apache.camel.util.toolbox.FlexibleAggregationStrategy">
    <property name="pickExpression">
        <xpath>
            //ID
        </xpath>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Property name set to `pick`, value as element:

```
<bean id="FlexibleAggregationStrategy"
    class="org.apache.camel.util.toolbox.FlexibleAggregationStrategy">
    <property name="pick">
        <xpath>
            //ID
        </xpath>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Property name set to `pickExpression`, value as attribute:

```
<bean id="FlexibleAggregationStrategy"
    class="org.apache.camel.util.toolbox.FlexibleAggregationStrategy">
    <property name="pickExpression" value="&lt;xpath&gt;//ID&lt;/xpath&gt;"/>
</bean>
```

Property name set to `pick`, value as attribute:

```
<bean id="FlexibleAggregationStrategy"
    class="org.apache.camel.util.toolbox.FlexibleAggregationStrategy">
    <property name="pick" value="&lt;xpath&gt;//ID&lt;/xpath&gt;"/>
</bean>
```

Each time, I get an error complaining that it's unable to find the property descriptor with the name I give it. The reason I try both `pick` and `pickExpression` is that, in [what appears to be the source code for FlexibleAggregationStrategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/util/toolbox/FlexibleAggregationStrategy.java), the variable holding the pick expression in the class is named `pickExpression`, but the method to set it is simply called `pick()`.

I don't have a perfect understanding of Spring XML, but based on what I know, using the `<property>` tag to set a variable value requires the bean to have getters and setters for that variable. Since `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` does not have getters and setters for `pickExpression`, I'm following the wrong approach anyway. However, if I'm reading [the XML Schema Definition for the `<bean>` tag](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd) correctly, the only way to send information to a bean is with the `<property>` tag or with constructor parameters. Since `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` has no constructors that set `pickExpression`, I haven't found a way to configure a `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` without writing Java code.

I've found references to something called "method injection" that might allow me to configure a `FlexibleAggregationStrategy`. However, the only instructions I've found involve writing a bean in Java. As such, this technique also involves writing Java code; in addition, it seems like it would be faster and more direct to just write my own `AggregationStrategy`.

As of now, neither the old nor new Apache Camel Wiki pages documenting the `<aggregator>` pattern does not mention `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` at all.

I have attempted a Google search for the term `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` to see if anybody has written any tutorials or documentation for using a `FlexibleAggregationStrategy`. As of now, the first two Google results I get are automatically-generated Javadoc for the `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` class. The third result is the github-hosted sourcecode I linked above. The fourth result is another question on this topic that I posted; this question was closed because I didn't understand how to write proper StackOverflow questions. The fifth result is the source code hosted on grepcode.com. The sixth result is the Javadoc for an interface I don't understand. The seventh result is a question somebody else asked on grokbase.com; the question has no answers. The eigth result is a question somebody else asked on qnalist.com that also has no answers. The ninth result seems to be from a mailing list involving committing the source code for the `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` class. The tenth result is the question from grokbase posted to osdir.com. Similar searches return mostly the same results; the other new results I find are equally unhelpful. I think that, if somebody had written a good guide for using `FlexibleAggregationStrategy`, it would come up in those searches.

Is there anybody who has used a `FlexibleAggregationStrategy` who can tell me how to set the `pickExpression` and `conditionPredicate` so I can use a `FlexibleAggregationStrategy`? If you know of anything else I would need to configure it, or any other common pitfalls surrounding it, that information would also be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the javadoc I'd say this class is not Camel XML-DSL-friendly and intended to be used with the Camel fluent Java-DSL. You're out of luck if you want to use it with Spring-DSL.

Your use case can probably be easier implemented by transforming the result body in the enrichment route using your xpath expression and then aggregate it with [UseLatestAggregationStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/UseLatestAggregationStrategy.html) which essentially makes the enrichment exchange the result of the aggregation:

```
<bean id="useLatest" class="org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.UseLatestAggregationStrategy"/>

<camel:route id="main">
    ...
    <camel:enrich uri="direct:enrich" strategyRef="useLatest"/>
    ...
</camel:route>

<camel:route id="enrichment">
    <camel:from uri="direct:enrich"/>

    ...enrichment processing here...

    <camel:setBody>
        <camel:xpath>//ID</camel:xpath>
    </camel:setBody>
</camel:route>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can see why the "zero Java code" feature would be technically useful if you're already using the Java DSL, but it sure seems to me like it would be a lot more useful if it worked with the other DSLs.

Answer (score 5):

Spring's XML format isn't really geared towards fluent builders but you can do it.  For example, to replicate this:

```
delegateStrategy = new FlexibleAggregationStrategy<Object>()
        .storeInBody()
        .accumulateInCollection(ArrayList.class)
        .pick(new SimpleExpression("${header[CamelFileName]}"));
```

would require this XML:

```
<bean id="_flexible0" class="org.apache.camel.util.toolbox.FlexibleAggregationStrategy"/>
<bean id="_flexible1" factory-bean="_flexible0" factory-method="storeInBody" />
<bean id="_flexible2" factory-bean="_flexible1" factory-method="accumulateInCollection">
  <constructor-arg value="java.util.ArrayList" />
</bean>
<bean id="fileNameListStrategy" factory-bean="_flexible2" factory-method="pick">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.model.language.SimpleExpression">
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${header[CamelFileName]}" />
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

As you see, it's not very concise, and requires creating a number of intermediate beans, but it is possible.

However, if you are not limited to zero custom Java, you could create your own AggregationStrategy that delegates to a FlexibleAggregationStrategy and use that in your XML.

Java portion:

```
public class FileNameListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    private CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy delegateStrategy;

    public FileNameListAggregationStrategy() {
        delegateStrategy = new FlexibleAggregationStrategy<Object>()
                .storeInBody()
                .accumulateInCollection(ArrayList.class)
                .pick(new SimpleExpression("${header[CamelFileName]}"));
    }

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        return delegateStrategy.aggregate(oldExchange, newExchange);
    }

}
```

XML portion:

```
<bean id="fileNameListStrategy" class="org.example.camel.FileNameListStrategy"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the client decided to move in another direction, so I can't vouch for the quality of your advice, but it certanly _looks_ reasonable and useful. Sorry.

Comment: No worries!  I'm doing something similar with Camel and I took it as a challenge to see if it could be done.  You can actually do quite a lot of "programming" in Spring XML, especially with SpEL in 3.0, but at some point it starts becoming quite absurd...