# Camel Throttling and correlationExpression

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I've searched high and low for a good example of using `correlationExpression` and can't seem to find a good working example.

What we're trying to do is throttle messages to a bunch of arbitrary queues. So have camel look at the `target_queue` property and throttle all messages with the same `target_queue` together.

See this question, it's pretty much the exact same thing: [Throttling based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368944/throttling-based-on-content)

What we're seeing is any message is throttled at a global rate, instead of being throttled in a group dictated by `target_queue`.

I think we fundamentally don't understand what the `correlationExpression` is meant do to, and we can't seem to find any good documentation or examples on it. Thank you for any help!

```xml
<camel:route
    id="com.xxx.camel.route.throttle"
    autoStartup="true">
    <camel:from
        uri="activemq:queue:com.xxx.camel.route.throttle.>?destination.consumer.prefetchSize=0" />
    <camel:throttle
        timePeriodMillis="10000"
        asyncDelayed="true">
        <camel:header>messages_per_10s_period</camel:header>
        <camel:correlationExpression>
            <camel:header>target_queue</camel:header>
        </camel:correlationExpression>
        <camel:routingSlip>
            <camel:header>target_queue</camel:header>
        </camel:routingSlip>
    </camel:throttle>
</camel:route>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a header with that name? What Camel version do you use?

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for taking a look. Yes, we verified both headers are present using the ActiveMQ Console. We also tried making messages_per_10s_period a fixed constant. We have the following camel jars deployed on the AMQ server: camel-core-2.24.3.jar  camel-jms-2.24.3.jar camel-spring-2.24.3.jar

Comment: Oh you are using an old EOL version of Camel. You can try with latest 2.25.x or with Camel v3. I am afraid I dont want to spend too much of my time on that old EOL release for free support.

Comment: :) We actually tried with Camel 2.25.4 as well, but with the same problem. And just to clarify, I greatly appreciate your time answering everyone for "free". I'd love kick you a gift card for some beers for your help.